# Can run jar from command line but not from shell script + permission denied

Tags: java, jar, permission-denied, archlinux

why can't I run a jar from a shellscript when double clicking it?

Failed to execute child process "~/start.sh" (Permission denied)

```
#!/bin/bash
java -jar test.jar
```

I'm running on Arch linux x64

Comment: Not exactly a Java question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is your script executable?

```
chmod +x start.sh
```

Comment: Tsss, what am I a noob... I'm a linux user for some months now and not knowing this is a shame.